# Ember.js cannot find my models definition

Tags: ember.js

I'm building an Ember application which requests data from the server using $.getJSON.
The problem is that Ember seems to not recognize my model and creates it automatically based on the json returned from the server (which has more properties than the ones in my model).

**Ember code**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ViewObject = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    ComputedProp: function () {
        return this.get('title') + ' - test';
    }.property('title')
});

App.ViewObjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        //served JSON structure is {title:'test',description:'abc',price:20,...}
        return $.getJSON(myServerUrl);
    },
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('viewObject', { path: '/' });
});
```

Using the Ember Inspector I can see that the model being used has all the properties returned from the server but if I try using the "ComputedProp" property nothing happens, which leads me to think that Ember isn't recognizing my model definition. I confirmed this by commenting my model - nothing changed after doing this.

Is there a naming convention that I'm not following?
How should I make Ember map the JSON from the server to my model?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Seems that this is happening because I'm not using Ember-data REST adapter, and instead making requests manually because it needs some tweaking to get along with my JSON API.
Things started working after I created a record from my model and filled with data:

```
var store = this.store;
$.getJSON().then(function(data){
    return store.createRecord('ViewObject', data);
});
```

It also would be great to know if what I'm doing here has any side-effects I should consider. Thanks

Comment: To do it the 'Ember way' I'd recommend customizing your Application or individual Model serializer to handle the tweaking: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html